# Hide title in tableau view

Tags: tableau-api

I want to hide the title("CT School Districts by Income and Grade Level Equivalents, 2009-13") of view when I display it on iframe. Should I change the src?

```
<iframe src="https://public.tableau.com/views/CTSchoolDistrictsbyIncomeandGradeLevels2009-13/Sheet1?:embed=y&:display_count=yes&:toolbar=n&:showVizHome=no"
        width="645" height="955"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Tableau menu, go to Worksheet and deselect "Show Title". Then re-save and re-publish to the server to get rid of the title.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to remove title from the shared link.
Just edit and republish dashboard.